# How do I view the data stored in a JWT? Using auth0 and express-jwt

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, auth0, express-jwt

Right now I believe I have most things setup correctly.  Auth0 is saving the jwt to the client who is then using it for future requests.  I use express-jwt to verify the token.  From reading the Auth0 docs, I think I need the client secret (when I use that to decode the jwt I get an odd error: `UnauthorizedError: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line`)  So I'm just wondering where about's this secret key comes from? 
Thanks

- Current code which just decodes the JWT into its signing scheme etc:

  `const jwtCheck = jwt({
      secret: jwks.expressJwtSecret({
          cache: true,
          rateLimit: true,
          jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
          jwksUri: 'https://xelitexirish.eu.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json'
      }),
      audience: 'https://www.shaunoneill.com',
      issuer: 'https://xelitexirish.eu.auth0.com/',
      algorithms: ['RS256']
  });`

Comment: In the code provided in your question, you are using `JWKS` and `RS256` - so no client secret required in order to verify the token. Difficult to comment further as you have offered limited info. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, as far as I knew Auth0 encodes the user profile into the JWT, so you can access the username and email etc.  This is the information that I'm trying to read

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - so you'd like to read the claims from body of JWT. Please see my answer below.

Comment: This website is helpful for just pasting the JWT in, and seeing what it looks like decoded too - https://jwt.io/

Comment: What I mean is, the host website can access the logged in users username, but if the server decodes the token, it just gets the base 64 decoded contents, not the email etc which is already in the token

Comment: My bad, I realised the solution. Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: Great to hear Shaun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comment from OP, to read the values of the body of JWT, simply base64 decode it. You can use a library for this, eg [jwt-decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode) for nodejs.

See example usage below (taken from README for lib):

```
var jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');
var token = 'eyJ0eXAiO.../// jwt token';

var decoded = jwtDecode(token);
console.log(decoded);

/* prints:
 * { foo: "bar",
 *   exp: 1393286893,
 *   iat: 1393268893  }
 */
```

The claims that will be in your Token (here, referring to ID Token) are dependent on what `scope` you provided when you authenticated. For instance, if you use `scope: openid profile email` you will get everything returned inside your ID Token.

*Here, assumed the JWT was verified using library, and now you have the JWT you'd like to read some if its claims from the body.*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express-jwt middleware then payload is by default saved in request object and you can access it like this `request.user`

Example for an endpoint:

```
//jwtMiddleware is express-jwt middleware
app.get('/', jwtMiddleware, function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.user);
  res.send('hello world');
});
```